# Facing issues with Omni-Channel

Tags: trigger, omnichannel

In our org. Omni-channel is set for routing of cases. For Case object trigger is also written. So omni-routing feature assigned a case from the queue to agents, but for that update on ownership of case record, update trigger is not fired.

Comment: I am facing exactly the same issue for OMNI Channel configuration on a custom object... Did you find a solution or work around for it..

Comment: Hi @user5352,
I found that, trigger & workflow rules do not fire for this scenario.
These functionalities are restricted by Salesforce.
Because when the omni-channel feature was built salesforce people wanted to make sure that their customers didn't run into any recursive loops from workflow rules or apex triggers firing. Please check the link--(https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000228601&language=en_US)

Answer (score 3):

Found that trigger & workflow rules do not fire for any updation by Omni-Channel.
These functionalities are restricted by Salesforce.
Because when the omni-channel feature was built salesforce people wanted to make sure that their customers didn't run into any recursive loops from workflow rules or apex triggers firing. Please check the link--(https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000228601&language=en_US)